# Succinctly expressing a set involving a relation between norms

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and define the set $$ K(y) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \|y + \alpha x\| < \|y\|, \alpha > 0 \} $$

I want to express this set in simpler terms so that I can better understand the nature of these vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Obviously, $\|y + \alpha x\| \leqslant \|y\| + \alpha\|x\|$ by the triangle inequality; however, I do not see how to put this together, or if it has any relevance to my problem.

Do any users have any insight into how I can express this relation inside of $K(y)$ more simply?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Multiplication by $\alpha$ **scales** (i.e., stretches or compresses and, possibly, reverses the direction of) the vector.  So, $y + \alpha x$ reads as "the translate of $y$ by the scaling $\alpha x$ of $x$.

One ambiguity in your definition of $K(y)$ is whether it means "for some $\alpha > 0$" or "for all $\alpha > 0$").  Whatever the case, your $K(y)$ is the set of all $x$'s such that translations by $\alpha x$ do not go outside of the sphere of radius $||y||$.  So, pick a $y$ in the 2-dimensional Euclidean space and compute its $K(y)$.

Comment: Would there be a simpler set notation than $K(y)$ above to represent this?

Comment: Not sure about simpler, but certainly more geometric.  Assuming the condition on $\alpha$ is "there exists", we see that $K(y)$ is the set of all vectors $x$ that have a rescaling $\alpha x$ that--upon acting on $y$ by translation--does not increase the norm of $y$.

What would it take for a translation by $\alpha x$ to increase the norm of $y$?  It would mean to "push" $y$ outside of the closed ball centered at the origin and with radius $||y||$.

Comment: Have you tried the 2-D case I suggested?  I find your definition of $K(y)$ a little troubling: $K(y)$ is either uninterestingly big or uninterestingly small.